# What is being omitted in this advertisement sentence?

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence.

> 部屋の数は六畳二間に、八畳とDK。

To give more context, this refers to residential sales advertisement. DK stands for dining kitchen.

> 部屋の数は六畳二間に(あり)、(他のは)八畳とDK(である)。

Is my "fill in the blanks" correct? Or perhaps there is nothing omitted.

I'm not sure I fully understand the sentence. What I got is "There are 2 rooms with 6 tatami mats, an 8 tatami mat area(?), And a dining room + kitchen.". Now, my teacher told me that there are only 2 rooms, the 8 tatami mat one is not a room. I don't know much about Japanese rooms, so I got confused.

Furthermore, is this 間 a counter for space?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 「部屋{へや}の数{かず}は六畳二間{ろくじょうふたま}に、八畳{はちじょう}と[DK]{ディーケイ}。」

Contrary to what your teacher told you, there are 4 rooms (including the DK) in this house/apartment.

「間{ま}」 is the counter for a room, so 「六畳二間{ろくじょうふたま}」 means "***two 6-tatami-size rooms***".  That is already two rooms.

「に」 here means "***and***", "***in addition to***", etc.  ← Important!

「八畳{はちじょう}」 in this context means "***one 8-tatami-size room***".  That is three rooms already.

「DK」 means a "dining kitchen" as you said.

Thus, there are four (4) rooms incuding the DK (and three, not including the DK).

There is not much "omitted" in the phrase in question. 「八畳」 here means 「八畳一間」.  「一間」 is read 「ひとま」.

To end on a cultural note, the terms「六畳」, 「八畳」, etc. ***do not*** imply that the rooms actually have tatami floors.  The room might have a wooden floor.  Those terms are used just for the size reference.

The type of home we just discussed is commonly called 「[3DK]{さんディーケイ}」 and below is a sample floor plan for such a place.  「洋{よう}」 means a "western-style" room with a wooden floor and the number 6 indicates the room size (equal to 6 tatami mats).  Thus, there is no tatami room in this particular apartment.  Only when you see, for instance, a 「和{わ} 6」, it means it is a real 6-tatami-size Japanese-style room.  「和」 means "Japanese" and 「洋」, "western".　Y'all have heard of "wagyu", right?

[image]
<sub>(source: [madori-ms.com](https://www.madori-ms.com/upimg/save/9/41.jpg))</sub>